# Push files locally through TFS to a web server?

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2015, jasmine, webserver, protractor

I have an E2E Automation project in TFS.  I'm using Protractor and Jasmine for the tests if that makes a difference.

I'm using a plugin for Protractor to generate reports and those reports are created locally and in the form of HTML files.  I have a 'Reports' folder in my TFS project, so currently the only way to make those reports accessible to others is to manually right click the reports folder in Visual Studio, click add items and select the reports, update the folder, and then do a check in.

My question(s):

1. Is there a way to automate that
2. Is there a better way to do that
3. Is there a way to assign a TFS path instead of a local path to the reporter itself? (protractor-jasmine2-screenshot-reporter is the report plugin)

And a side question:
If those can update into TFS on every run, what's the best way to pull those files into some type of webserver / index page for anyone to view them without going through TFS?

Answer (score 0):

You're approaching this all backwards. You want to run your Jasmine tests as part of your build/CI process and publish the results to the build that ran them, not by committing them as changes to your code repository.

You should be able to follow some instructions along [these lines](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/developers/articles/week04aug15/nunit-and-jasmine-js-unit-tests-in-tfs-vso-vnext-build/) to accomplish it. Basically, use the "Visual Studio Test" task pointing to a Jasmine test file. It will run it using the Chutzpah test adapter and generate a test results file that the "Visual Studio Test" task can translate into a report to be attached to the build.

Comment: Thanks for the reply - I briefly skimmed the page you linked, would this still work even if the Jasmine tests are not part of Unit Tests.  My suite is basically all front-end / UI testing.  So it's not exactly linked to the project I'm running tests against. If that made any sense..